# How to merge several JSON objects in one and put values from both of them in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a JSON file with the structure like in the code below:

```
{
    "results": [
      {

        "name": "First Candidate",
        "result": 52,
        "victory": "winner",
        "region": "First region",
        "constituencyName": "First constituency",
        "constituencyNumber": 1,
        "partyName": "Ruling party",
        "partyShort": "PR",
        "partyStatus": "Right"
      },
      {
        "name": "Second Candidate",
        "result": 48,
        "victory": "looser",
        "region": "First region",
        "constituencyName": "First constituency",
        "constituencyNumber": 1,
        "partyName": "Opposition party",
        "partyShort": "OP",
        "partyStatus": "Left"
      }
   ]
}
```

There are separate DIVs for all objects now. I'm trying to merge objects with uniform "constituencyName" in one, bind this selection with one DIV and place all candidates names related with selected constituency in a tooltip.

The present view:

[image]

My purpose:

[image]

It is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/nwt2n04y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this :

```
var input = {
"results": [
  {

    "name": "First Candidate",
    "result": 52,
    "victory": "winner",
    "region": "First region",
    "constituencyName": "First constituency",
    "constituencyNumber": 1,
    "partyName": "Ruling party",
    "partyShort": "PR",
    "partyStatus": "Right"
  },
  {
    "name": "Second Candidate",
    "result": 48,
    "victory": "looser",
    "region": "First region",
    "constituencyName": "First constituency",
    "constituencyNumber": 1,
    "partyName": "Opposition party",
    "partyShort": "OP",
    "partyStatus": "Left"
  }
  ]};

var constituencyMap =
input.results.reduce(function(p, c){
      p[c.constituencyName] = p[c.constituencyName] || []

      p[c.constituencyName].push(c);

      return p;          
  }, {});

var result = Object.keys(constituencyMap).map(function(key){
                    return {constituencyName:key, value:constituencyMap[key]};
              });
// the result will be an array to retrieve the name
// result[index].constituencyName will have constituencyName
// and result[index].value will have value
```

Comment: I've used your code, it works, thanks. But now I can't bind new data structure with the elements in my visualization. I'm trying to assign all the data related with every constituency to separate rectangles, but I can't manage with it. Could you tell me what I do wrong? My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/mnngp3do/ Could you also explain me how to get an access to the names in the existing data structure? I need to pull out both of them and put in the tooltip. But I can't understand how to do it in this irregular structure

Comment: I have modified the code to show how to get the name